# Realtimesync does not monitor directories correctly

Tags: windows-10, realtimesync, freefilesync

I set up Realtimesync ([FreeFileSync](https://freefilesync.org/), newest Version 11.6) to monitor two directories:

`C:\Directory1`

`C:\Users\username\Desktop`

and run a sync script when changes are detected.

Using the script by itself works fine, but unfortunately when I add/change files in the monitored directories the script isn't executed.

Any ideas how to do the troubleshooting here?

Comment: There are a bunch of settings for this app. Did you set the user configurable idle time setting? This time has to pass before sync will take place.

Comment: @John I left it at 60 sec, and waited definitely longer.

Comment: Thanks . I will look around a bit more.

Comment: @John I was playing around with it a bit. It seems to be a bug, changing the idle to a different value does the trick... thanks for the idea!

Comment: Feel free to add an answer, otherwise I'll do it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That was my thinking as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From:  [Real Time Sync](https://freefilesync.org/manual.php?topic=realtimesync)

> RealTimeSync receives change notifications directly from the operating
> system in order to avoid the overhead of repeatedly polling for
> changes. Each time a file or folder is created/updated/deleted in the
> monitored directories or their sub directories, RealTimeSync waits
> until a user-configurable idle time has passed in which no further
> changes were detected, and then runs the command line. This makes sure
> the monitored folders are not in heavy use when starting a
> synchronization.

This may be sensitive to the time value entered.  Try different ones.

**Note from OP:** It seems to be a bug (at least in my version after I did an update, the previous version did not have this problem), changing the idle to a different value at least once does the trick (you can change it back afterwards)... thanks for the idea!